Dynamically pick columns for RowMeans calculation in R
I'm trying to counter a barrier in a series of steps that I acknowledge might be restructured in a different approach, but for the time being this is way things are, hence my very specific question.
I have a dataframe data of products (Country, Brand, Product_Name) and quarterly records of Value and Units sold in wide-format as such:



Country
Brand
Product_Name
Q1.2018.Units
Q1.2018.Value
Q2.2018.Units
Q2.2018.Value
...
Q1.2024.Value




Austria
Brand A
Prod 123
1120
11200
2340
23400
...
59000


Belgium
Brand A
Prod 456
--------
--------
--------
--------
...
38293


Croatia
Brand B
Prod ABC
--------
--------
489
58392
...
957837



I have code that detects the date of market entry of a product, which is the first quarter it has recorded values, so I can get one of the two following new columns (depending on whether I choose the entry date column name or index):



Country
Brand
Product_Name
Q1.2018.Units
Q1.2018.Value
Q2.2018.Units
Q2.2018.Value
...
Q1.2024.Value
mkt_entry_date
mkt_entry_col




Austria
Brand A
Prod 123
1120
11200
2340
23400
...
59000
Q1.2018
4


Belgium
Brand A
Prod 456
--------
--------
--------
--------
...
38293
Q3.2020
24


Croatia
Brand B
Prod ABC
--------
--------
489
58392
...
957837
Q2.2018
6



Now I'm iterating over the quarters with a for-loop and, for each quarter of every year on record, calculating a price variable (and some other metrics), avoiding going the dplyr way in order to dynamically build variable names (legacy code, before dicovering the 'walrus' operator).
for (i in 2:n_qrts){
  
  curr_qrt = substr(colnames(data_c)[st_col_c - 2 + n_cols*i],1,7) #this fetches the quarter name from the ordered variable names
  data_c[, paste0(curr_qrt,".Price")] = data_c[, paste0(curr_qrt,".Value")] / 
    data_c[, paste0(curr_qrt,".Units")] #this computes a new variable price for each quarter in scope
  }

I want to compute the mean of the previous quarters to date - e.g. for Q1 2018 nothing would be calculated. For Q1 2024, it would yield the mean of all Q1s from 2018-2023.
The code that follows is inside the for-loop and crashes with an error for pick():  ! Selections can't have missing values.:
data = mutate(data, "{curr_qrt}_mean" := rowMeans(pick(names(data)[grep("pattern for current Q's units"), names(data))[grep("pattern for current Q's units"), names(data)) >= "market_col"[grep("pattern for current Q's units"), names(data)) < current_col]]]), na.rm = TRUE))

(here, I tried to get all the column names that match the quarter currently being analysed with grep and then slicing that with the market entry column and the column corresponding to the current quarter)
What other approach should I take, possibly keeping it baseR, while maintaining the loop through all the quarters?
(@thelatemail suggested pivoting to long-format and doing it the tidyR way, but it strikes me as weird that there's no way of slicing the output of grep and eventually passing an empty vector to pick())

Usually it would be better to format a table like this as a "long" table with columns like:  Country/Brand/ProductName/Year/Quarter/Units/Value - then you don't have to worry about trying to pick columns by name/regex and there are no missing values that you have to loop over. The whole Tidyverse and the dplyr package exists on the basis that you work with "tidy" data, which typically avoids these wide files.

I see you acknowledge this at the top of the question, but it really will be painful to keep with this process when restructuring will only be a couple of lines of pivot_longer code.

After you pivot_longer as suggested by the previous comments, you can sort by time, group by product, and then use lag(cummean(., na.rm = TRUE)) for your last computation.

thank you both! I wonder if there is no baseR way to approach this (yes, I mixed dplyr in there, but originally, because of variable name creation, it was done with baseR only, as I illustrated with the additional code in the last edit).

@HenriqueVasconcelos - absolutely you can do this with base R. The 'tidy' approach to handling data doesn't require the tidyverse. ?stats::reshape the data to long and do a grouped operation with by or ave.
